# HTML Text label misplaced when in line validation appears

Tags: html, forms, view

I have a simple form with a date validation which works fine:

[image: Screnshoot Before problem]

The problem is that when the validation kicks in, the "End Date" label gets misplaced as you can see (is above the date field box/calendar):

[image: Screnshoot after problem]

The code related is the following (it's just a form):

```
<form name="senstageaddform">

    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="ed_senStartDate" class="text-label">
            {{i18n "EDUCATION_SEN_START_DATE"}} <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="date standard-text-field" maxlength="16" id="ed_senStartDate" name="startDate"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="ed_senEndDate" class="text-label">{{i18n "EDUCATION_SEN_END_DATE"}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="date standard-text-field" maxlength="16" id="ed_senEndDate" name="endDate"/>
    </div>

</form>
```

Is there any way to "pack" the form or any way to stop this happening?

Any hint please?

Thanks everyone